# How to see which DB schema my Spring Boot application is connecting during application startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spring boot 1.5.8 application which uses Autoconfiguration to connect Oracle DB. I have defined all the connection params/properties in application.properties. Is there any way can I print which DB schema and connection params application is using during application startup.

Here the goal is to see does Spring Boot application using all the connection properties defined in the file during application startup or not.Want to print or see Host,port,Schema,DatabaseName used by the app during app starting.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449322/how-to-log-jdbc-connection-info-on-org-springframework-jdbc-cannotgetjdbcconnectionexception

Answer (score 0):

Springboot 2.x with Hikari Datasource I can print out the info

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE

[image]